# Python Regex not matching at start of string?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm going through a binary file with regexes extracting data, and I'm having a problem with regex I can't track down.

This is the code I'm having issues with:

```
        z = 0
        for char in string:
            self.response.out.write('|%s' % char.encode('hex'))
            z+=1
            if z > 20:
                self.response.out.write('<br>')
                break

        title = []
        string = re.sub('^\x72.([^\x7A]+)', lambda match: append_match(match, title), string, 1)
        print_info('Title', title)

def append_match(match, collection, replace = ''):
    collection.append(match.group(1))
    return replace
```

This is the content of the first 20 chars in string when this runs:

|72|0a|50|79|72|65|20|54|72|6f|6c|6c|7a|19|54|72|6f|6c|6c|62|6c

It returns nothing, except if I remove the ^, in which case it returns "Troll" (not the quotes) which is 54726F6C6C. It should be returning everything up to the \x7a as I read it.

What's going on here?

Comment: Your input string doesn't start with a `\x72` character--it starts with a pipe. *edit Never mind...I think I misinterpreted your input example.

Comment: Yeah sorry. Was making it easier to tell each distinct char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\x0A` (=newline) won't be matched by the dot by default. Try adding the [dotall flag](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) to your pattern, for example:

```
re.sub('(?s)^\x72.([^\x7A]+)....
```

Comment: You're my hero. Adding the dotall worked. What is the (?s) you added though?

Comment: This is the same dotall flag, but added inline to the expression. I usually prefer this syntax as it makes expressions clear and self-contained.